# Parsing in any encoding

Tags: php, parsing, encoding, html-parsing

I use file_get_contents function to parse the remote pages. The problem in encoding. When i trying to parse site with utf-8 all work good but when encode is cp1251 i have in result next:

�����.UA / ������� ������: ������, ����, ���������, ������, ������, �������, �������� � ��., ������, ������, �����, ����, ����� � ������ ������

This function working like a facebook link publish. User enter the link and get result. I need some function or method to parse sites in any encoding. Script encoding - UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [mb_check_encoding()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php) and try some encodings until you see one fit.

However, you should play around a bit with the stream context of [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or even use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to fetch the site. This way, you can get the headers, and among them, the encoding used for the document. Once you know the encoding, it should be easy to [convert it to UTF-8](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).